# How to display logged user in application, JSF 2.1 , error Method not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-webflow

I have an application in jsf 2.1, in which the login is store in the database(postgresql) via hibernate, my application is made in spring, using spring security i can login successfully :

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The problem is when i want show info about the user logged in the application, in jsf i can show the name  via EL (Expression Language) :

```
#{request.userPrincipal.name}
```

but i want to show the other info store in the database, i use a hibernate method:

```
public Users getUser(String login) {
    List<Users> userList = new ArrayList<Users>();  
    Query query = openSession().createQuery("from Users u where u.login = :login");  
    query.setParameter("login", login);  
    userList = query.list();  
    if (userList.size() > 0)  
        return userList.get(0);  
    else
        return null;
}
```

and i call this via jsf bean like this showUser:

```
 @Component
 @Scope("session")
 public class UsersBean {
private String login;
private String name_user;
private String pass;
private HabilitacionVehicular_InscripcionFacade habilitacionVehicular_InscripcionFacade;

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getName_user() {
    return name_user;
}
public void setName_user(String name_user) {
    this.name_user = name_user;
}
public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}
public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}
public Users showUser(String login) throws DataAccessException, EntityNotFoundException{
    return habilitacionVehicular_InscripcionFacade.getUser(login);
}
```

But I can't show it in the application

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{usersBean.showvUser()}" var="c"
        styleClass="order-table" headerClass="order-table-header"
        rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Customer ID
            </f:facet>
                #{c.login}
        </h:column>
```

This give me the error:

```
 Error: /WEB-INF/flows/main/main.xhtml @24,58 value="#{usersBean.showvUser()}": Method showvUser not found
```

And this if i combine EL and the method:

```
 Error: /WEB-INF/flows/main/main.xhtml @24,58 value="#{usersBean.showvUser(#{request.userPrincipal.name})}" Failed to parse the expression [#{usersBean.showvUser(#{request.userPrincipal.name})}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method signature is

```
public Users showUser(String login)
```

however, you call

```
#{usersBean.showvUser()}
```

where there is no method like `userBean#showUser()`

Second there is no need to use second el resolver `( #{} )` if you pass a parameter to action method. Use

```
#{usersBean.showvUser(request.userPrincipal.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to run an additional query for the user's details because spring security keeps the details of the currently logged in user in the security context. All you need to do is to make that information accessible through EL, for instance by putting the following getter in a backing bean:

```
public MyUser getCurrentUser() {
    return (MyUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

where your UserDetailsService returns instances of `MyUser`.

Incidentally, are you sure that `#{requst.userPrincipal}` isn't a `MyUser` object, too? If it is, you could simply use `#{requst.userPrincipal.anotherProperty}` (where your UserDetailsService returns an object with a property named "anotherProperty") instead ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot used this method for fetching data because you are trying to load data table from database. So use some other techniques for examples when your page is loaded just call the load method for data table population and bind the list with data table. In your method you are just sending some parameter to the server but when JSF page goes it doesn't found any method which takes no param so throws error.
So you just send some param using jsf:param or some other way and try to load the data table.Hope this will help you

Or you try this

## {usersBean.showUser(#{usersBean.name_user})}

Regards